# Parsing an XML File for a single word/phrase

Tags: c#, http

this is a small part of my code that allows me to request a file through a load balancer, reading this XML file gives me the server's name (*only node inside the XML Document*) if the machine isn't inside the LAN then it won't be able to query the website.  I give it a longer timeout to make sure that I don't get a ton of errors emailed to me if the network is laggy.

Here is the XML file Structure.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Server>
    JSODYAPP01T
</Server>
```

Here is the Code that retrieves the information

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(xmlLocation);
request.Timeout = 90000;

using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    while (xmlReader.Read())
    {
        if (xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
        {
            serverName = xmlReader.Value.ToString();
            serverName = serverName.Replace("\r", "");
            serverName = serverName.Replace("\n", "");
            serverName = serverName.Replace(" ", "");
        }
    }
}
```

is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Linq to XML is your friend

```
var serverName = XDocument.Load(response.GetResponseStream()).Element("Server").Value;
```

Your code will be easily broken if someone adds a node to the `XML`, and your code should be as flexible as possible. Never do such an assumption (It's gonna be the first node)

Your method is blocking, consider making it `asynchronous`.

```
using (var response = await request.GetResponseAsync()){

}
```

And by the way, C# got type inference, so why bother typing the type? Use `var` instead

```
var request = WebRequest.Create(xmlLocation);
```

Comment: Don't forget `.Trim()` at the end.

Comment: @Malachi [Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb397926.aspx) is specifically designed to handle loading and manipulating data in a consistent way. The code above allows you to load the XML into a format where you can *specifically request the XML element you want*. This means that you don't need to worry about formatting issues, XML syntax changes, response changes and whitespace trimming.

Comment: as far as blocking, this is the single task that this application was created for, I don't want it running next to itself, it should run one instance and only one instance at a time, it will return the same results a majority of the time.

Comment: @Malachi I can't thing of an example where type inference can cause problems, because C# in strongly typed, type inference is not dynamic. Blocking wise, I don't know about your application, but it doesn't sound right to run a process just to get the server name! Does it? I don't know

Comment: The application connects to a page on a load balanced app server to figure out which app server the user is actually connected to through the Load Balancer. it's a way to create a list of all the people on a specific App Server, or the full load on the system.

Answer (score 2):

It should be more efficient to use a `Regex` to replace all those patterns in one swift move:

```
serverName = Regex.Replace(xmlReader.Value.ToString(), @"[\r\n ]+", "");
```

If you'd like to remove any kind of whitespace, it could be even simpler:

```
serverName = Regex.Replace(xmlReader.Value.ToString(), @"\s+", "");
```

Comment: REGEX? who uses REGEX?  lol JK.  for something like that you are probably right, I didn't even stack my `Replace` statements either, but that sounds more like something a VB programmer would do..